# Adding multiple <Fields /> in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I should have both question input and answer input in a `<Field/>`. Because of that redux-form docs tells me to use `<Fields/>`.

```
<Fields names={['question1', 'answer1']}
    component={this.renderInputGroupField} />
<Fields names={['question2', 'answer2']}
    component={this.renderInputGroupField} />
<Fields names={['question3', 'answer3']}
    component={this.renderInputGroupField} />
```

rendering fields with this

```
renderInputGroupField(fields){
    return(
        <div className="form-group d-block">
            <div className="form-group input-group">
                <select className="form-select" >
                    <option>Multiple-Choice</option>
                    <option>Open-Ended</option>
                </select>
                <input {...fields.question1.input}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-input"
                    placeholder="Type your question..."/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input {...fields.answer1.input}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-input"
                    placeholder="Comma-separated answer choices" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

To make `renderInputGroupField` work, I should add `{...fields.answer1.input}` into `<input />` as above. Here is the problem. Names that are passed into fields are different and I can't find a way to change `...fields.answer1.input` to `...fields.answer2.input` dynamically.

I am not sure if I was able to explain it properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems you want to use the renderInputGroupField as a reusable component. Quickly testing, it looks like redux-form also sends back that list of names you originally gave it. You should be able to access those properties of fields that you listed in the names array using their index in that array, like below.

```
return(
  <div className="form-group d-block">
    <div className="form-group input-group">
      <select className="form-select">
        <option>Multiple-Choice</option>
        <option>Open-Ended</option>
      </select>
      <input {...fields[fields.names[0]].input}
             type="text"
             className="form-input"
             placeholder="Type your question..."/>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input {...fields[fields.names[1]].input}
             type="text"
             className="form-input"
             placeholder="Comma-separated answer choices" />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried `fields.names[0]` to target the name but looks like the way I was writing, was wrong. Your answer fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I thought about putting entire questions under question 'q' object. So, in fields I'll be passing `names={['q.question1', 'q.answer1']}`, how does it change the `{...fields[fields.names[0]].input}`. Because names[0] now contains 'q.question1' and some how q. should be cut out to target the input.

Comment: You can change it to {...fields.q[fields.names[0].split('.')[1]]} for question and {...fields.q[fields.names[1].split('.')[1]]} for answer.